# Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

In general, it does not always hold that if

$$AB=AC \implies B=C.\tag{1}$$

Is there any specific case where $(1)$ holds?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible (multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ and see)

Comment: Let write the matrix equation like this $A\left( n,k\right) \cdot \left( B\left( k,ℓ\right) -C\left( k,m\right) \right) =0$ so just if l equal m you get B equal C

Comment: The implication (1) holds if the (possibly rectangular) matrix $A$ is injective.

Comment: And $A$ is invertible so long as det($A$)$\ne$0

Comment: Two more cases:- if A is an identity matrix....another is if B,C are power of A

Comment: This is also not a question about physics and belongs in [math.se]

Comment: @Qmechanic  Referring to your comment: I think you wanted to write *injective* and not *surjective*

Comment: @Valter Moretti: Ups. You're right! Applied superpowers retroactively.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let $A$ not be a zero divisor. This happens when $A$ is invertible, since units are not zero divisors.

Then $AB=AC$ implies $A(B-C)=0$. By hypothesis, $B-C = 0$ and so $B=C$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a necessary and sufficient condition.

> Given an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $AB = AC \implies B = C$ for all $n \times k$ matrices $B,C$,
> 2. $A$ has a trivial nullspace,
> 3. The columns of $A$ are linearly independent,
> 4. The matrix $A$ has rank $n$ (i.e. "full column-rank"),
> 5. There exists a matrix $M$ such that $MA = I$.

*Proof:*

$1 \implies 2$: Suppose that $A$ satisfies condition 1.  Note that $A 0 = 0$, where $0$ here denotes the $n \times 1$ zero-vector.  For any $n \times 1$ column vector $x$, we have
$$
Ax = A 0 \implies x = 0
$$
So, $A$ has a trivial nullspace.

That $2 \iff 3 \iff 4$ is something covered in most introductory linear algebra texts, so I won't dwell on it here.

$4 \implies 5$: This is quick using pseudoinverses or the fact that $A^TA$ and $A$ have the same rank, but I'll avoid using that here.

Suppose that $A$ has full column-rank; it necessarily holds that $m \geq n$.  Because row-rank and column-rank are equal, $A$ has $n$ linearly independent rows.

Let $J$ denote the $n \times m$ matrix that we get by taking the $m \times m$ identity matrix and removing all rows except for the ones corresponding to the rows that form the linearly independent rows of $A$. Then $(JA)$ is a square, invertible matrix (in particular, $JA$ is the matrix attained by removing all the rows of $A$ except for those in our chosen linearly independent set).

So, we have $(JA)^{-1}JA = I$.  Thus, $M = (JA)^{-1}J$ satisfies $MA = I$.

$5 \implies 1$:  Suppose that $AB = AC$.  Multiplying both sides by $M$, we have 
$$
(MA)B = (MA)C \implies B = C.
$$
So, condition 1 holds.