# Prove the existence of left and right inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

A theorem states the following

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $m \times n$ matrix such that rank $\mathbf{A} = r$.

(a) $\mathbf{A}$ has a right-inverse if and only if and only if $r = m$ and $m \leq n$

(b) $\mathbf{A}$ has a left-inverse if and only if and only if $r = n$ and $n \leq m$

I cannot find a proof for this anywhere though. So can anyone please provide one so I can realize *why* this is true?

Comment: How do you define the rank?

Comment: Like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

Comment: [My post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3324458/81360) covers the case of the left-inverse

Answer (score 2):

For (a), $A$ has right inverse if and only if the linear transformation $\textsf{L}_A : F^n \to F^m$ has right inverse, and this happens if and only if $\textsf{L}_A$ is onto, that is $\operatorname{im}(\textsf L_A) = F^m$ or equivalently $\operatorname{rank}( \textsf L_A) = m$.

For (b) is similar, use the fact that $f$ has a left inverse iff $f$ is one-to-one and use the dimension theorem.

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks. But what about $m \leq n$ and $n \leq m$? :)

Comment: And could you maybe elaborate a little on why " $\textsf{L}_A$ is onto, that is $\operatorname{im}(\textsf L_A) = F^m$" - like why this is true? Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Interpret these statements as about the linear transformation $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ given by $x \mapsto Ax$. Then $A$ has a right-inverse iff the transformation is surjective. And $A$ has a left-inverse iff the transformation is injective.

Comment: Thanks! But *why* if there a right-inverse only if the transformation is subjective and a left-inverse only if the transformation is injective? The *why* /explanation is more what I am looking for :))

Comment: @npp, these two facts are true for functions in general. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Injections_can_be_undone for instance.

Comment: Yea but there must still be some reasoning for the implications, right?