# How to find one-sided inverse of a non-invertible linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose I am working with the linear transformation from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$ given by a $2\times3$ matrix say 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 0 & 5 \\  
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
this matrix has no left inverse but has a right inverse matrix of order $3\times2$ producing identity $I_2$ matrix.

How to find such a right inverse matrix?Is there any method to do so?

Comment: You just repeated the same matrix.

Comment: I outline one method of producing a [left-inverse here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3324458/81360). You could also use the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivot columns of a full row rank matrix will form an invertible submatrix, to whose inverse you could add zero rows for the free columns to get a right inverse.

So in this case, the pivot submatrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\4&0\end{bmatrix}$ has inverse $\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{4}\\\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{8}\end{bmatrix}$ which gives the right inverse $$\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{4}\\\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{8}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

An $m\times n$ matrix $A$ (with coefficients in a field, such as $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$) has a right inverse if and only if $m\leq n$ and $\mathrm{rank}(A)=m$. An $m\times n$ matrix has a left inverse if and only if $n\leq m$ and $\mathrm{rank}(A)=n$.

In the first case, you can think of $A$ as representing a surjective linear transformation $\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{F}^m$. To find an inverse to a surjective function, you just need to find a pre-image to each element of a basis for $\mathbb{F}^m$ and define the map using them.

That means, finding a solution to $A\mathbf{x}_i=\mathbf{e}_i$, where $\mathbf{e}_i$ is the $m\times 1$ vector that has a $1$ in the $i$th component and zeroes elsewhere (any solution will do). Then the matrix whose columns are the $\mathbf{x}_i$ will be a right inverse of $A$.

This can be done all at once by doing row reduction of the matrix $(A|I_m)$, where $I_m$ is the $m\times m$ identity. For instance, here,
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
1&2&3&1&0\\
4&0&5&0&1
\end{array}\right) &\to \left(\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
1&2&3&1&0\\
0&-8&-7&-4&1
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
1&2&3&1&0\\
0^{\vphantom{2^2}} & 1 & \frac{7}{8} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{8}
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
1 & 0 & \frac{5}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4}\\
0^{\vphantom{2^2}} & 1 & \frac{7}{8} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{8}
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$
So, the solutions to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{e}_1$ are of the form
$$\begin{align*}
x&= -\frac{3}{8}t\\
y&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{7}{8}t\\
z&=t
\end{align*}$$
and the solutions to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{e}_2$ are of the form
$$\begin{align*}
x&= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{5}{4}s\\
y&= -\frac{1}{8} - \frac{7}{8}s\\
z&=s
\end{align*}$$
Thus, the right inverses of $A$ are the matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{-3}{8}t & \frac{1}{4}-\frac{5}{4}s\\
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{7}{8}t & -\frac{1}{8} - \frac{7}{8}s\\
t & s
\end{array}\right).$$
Setting $s=t=0$ gives you the matrix from Michael Biro's answer.

Left inverses are similar, and left as a thought exercise for the reader.